# How to add conditions in a ebean query?

Tags: java, orm, ebean

I have a query on my model that I am filtering by the properties of my model, Id, Title, and so on. However, How do I wrap all my conditions into a `or` I looked into `disjunction` but I did not find a way to add the conditions only when there is a value.

```
  Query<Ticket> query = Ebean.find(Ticket.class);

            if(filter.getId() != null){
                 query.where().eq("id", filter.getId());
            }

            if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(filter.getTitle())){
                query.where().icontains("title",filter.getTitle());
            }

            return query.findList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the google group, I've just found the solution:

```
   Junction<Ticket> filters = Ebean.find(Ticket.class).where().disjunction();

    if(filter.getId() != null){
      filters.add(Expr.eq("id", filter.getId()));
    }
    return filters.endJunction().findList();
```

disjunction returs a List of Juntions and then I check the value and add an Expr on the list.